# Does OSX have an equivalent of SendMessage win32 API?

Tags: c++, macos

So I can send a message such as keystroke to a window that is not active

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933203/what-is-the-equivalent-if-any-to-the-c-windows-sendmessage-on-the-mac?rq=1

Comment: that's great but how do I get the handle to the window?  It would be for an external application.

Comment: You could have, you know, mentioned that in the original question. In general you shouldn't do that. But if you have a legitimate reason to, you can look into [OS X Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/accessibility.html). If you can convince the user to turn it on in the system prefs, then your app can use it.